# Switching between branches in Git using visual studio interface and previewing changes

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2017. I created a branch (TestBranch) of my master and made a static text change in a View (.Net Core) after checking out the TestBranch. The change is saved, but not committed or staged. I want to preview the Master branch now that doesn't have the static text change. I switched the branch from TestBranch to Master and ran the application, but the static text change is reflected on the web page.

Is it possible in Git local to preview changes of only one branch? If yes, what is wrong in the above scenario?

I don't have Git explicitly installed, I can only use the Git that came with the Visual Studio. By the way, I am working on my local and there is no Git remote repository for my solution.

Comment: just commit in your branch

Comment: Thanks Alexan. It works the way I want after I commit the changes.